automate desktop application using playwright (typescript) with webview2
Using Playwright with TypeScript I'm trying to automate desktop application. I'm able to run the application as server and access it over web browser. even I'm able to run the application with support of webview2 and get it's web socket URL. but I'm not able to connect the instance with play wright. getting following error.
Error: browserType.connectOverCDP: Protocol error (Browser.setDownloadBehavior): Browser context management is not supported.
import { chromium, Browser, Page } from 'playwright';
import { exec } from 'child_process';
import axios from 'axios';

const WEBVIEW2_PORT = port details;
const APP_PATH = `"application path"`;

export async function launchDesktopApp(): Promise<{ browser: Browser, page: Page }> {
  // Launch the desktop application with WebView2 support
  exec(`${APP_PATH} --webEngineArgs --remote-debugging-port=${WEBVIEW2_PORT}`, { env: { ...process.env, WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS: `--webEngineArgs --remote-debugging-port=${WEBVIEW2_PORT}` } });

  // Wait for the application to start and WebView2 to be available
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 15000));

  // Get the WebSocket debugger URL
  let webSocketDebuggerUrl: string | null = null;
  while (!webSocketDebuggerUrl) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:${WEBVIEW2_PORT}/json/version/`);
      webSocketDebuggerUrl = response.data.webSocketDebuggerUrl;
      console.log("websocket is " + webSocketDebuggerUrl);
    } catch {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    }
  }

  // Connect to the WebView2 instance using Playwright
  const browser = await chromium.connectOverCDP(webSocketDebuggerUrl);
  const page = (await browser.contexts()[0].pages())[0];

  return { browser, page };
}

tried running it on chromium.
I need a support here to resolve this issue with playwright using typescript
